# Rewriting integral as Iterated Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Rewrite the integral $$\iint_D xy^2 \, dA$$ as an iterated integral where $D$ is the region bounded by $x+y=-1$ and $x+y^2=1$.

I tried to do the question and I got $\int_{-3}^0 \int_{-1}^2xy^2 \, dy \, dx$. Is this correct?

Comment: It is not correct, your region is not a box, so your inner limits will depend on the outer variable of integration.

Comment: I would integrate w.r.t $x$ first. So integrate $x$ between the curves $-(y+1)$ and $(1-y^2)$. A picture will definitely help what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

$D$ is a region bounded by a line and a parabola. The region of your proposed double integral however is $\{(x,y):-1 \leq y \leq 2, -3 \leq x \leq 0\}$, which is a rectangle.

My advice to you is to draw out the region $D$.

[image: Taken from Wolfram Alpha]

We can then see the simultaneous constraints $-y-1 \leq x \leq 1-y^2$ and $-1 \leq y \leq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You have set
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{}
-1 \leqslant y \leqslant 2 \\
-1-y \leqslant x \leqslant 1-y^2
\end{array} \right\rbrace = \\ \left\lbrace \begin{array}{}
-3 \leqslant x \leqslant 0 \\
-1-x \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{1-x}
\end{array} \right\rbrace \cup  \left\lbrace \begin{array}{}
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
-\sqrt{1-x} \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{1-x}
\end{array} \right\rbrace
$$
so integral
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{2}\int\limits_{-1-y}^{1-y^2}xy^2\,dx\,dy =\int\limits_{-3}^{0}\int\limits_{-1-x}^{\sqrt{1-x}}xy^2\,dy\,dx + \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1-x}}^{\sqrt{1-x}}xy^2\,dy\,dx $$